# Appium IOS tests very slow on 1.8.1

Tags: java, appium-ios

I've recently had to upgrade to Appium 1.8.1 and XCode 9.4 and my appium IOS tests are now extremely slow. There's a long pause between simple commands such as clicking buttons and entering text.

The majority of my elements are located by ID, so it's not xpaths slowing the tests down. Has anyone managed to find a way to speed their tests up? I've tried identifying elements by iOS predicate, but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by upgrading the appium java client on the pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also had to upgrade the selenium java dependency to 3.12.0

I'm currently on Java 8 and appium 1.8, but the upgrade also had the following affect on my code:

- TouchAction methods have changed (eg. press used to expect 2 int parameters, it now expects PointOption.point parameter)